# Hasura action handler does not exist (Name or service not known)

Tags: docker, ubuntu, graphql, hasura, hasura-docker

I have an instance of Hasura running in the Docker container and action handler API written in NodeJS/Express running directly on the machine.

When I test everything locally it works like a charm ( macOS M1 ), but when I replicate the same setup on the server ( Ubuntu 20.04 ) it returns an action handler does not exist error.

All other queries and mutations work well, just actions return this error

You can see that both Hasura and NodeJS apps are running

[hasura docker container](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v0Si9.png)

[localhost api call](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rXr79.png)

In local development my action handler base url is

> http://host.docker.internal:5000/api

and it is working fine.
I have also tried

> http://localhost:5000/api

> http://127.0.0.1:5000/api

This is the exact error Hasura action call returns

```
{
"errors": [
    {
        "extensions": {
            "internal": {
                "error": {
                    "type": "http_exception",
                    "message": "ConnectionFailure Network.Socket.getAddrInfo (called with preferred socket type/protocol: AddrInfo {addrFlags = [], addrFamily = AF_UNSPEC, addrSocketType = Stream, addrProtocol = 0, addrAddress = 0.0.0.0:0, addrCanonName = Nothing}, host name: Just \"host.docker.internal\", service name: Just \"5000\"): does not exist (Name or service not known)"
                },
                "response": null,
                "request": {
                    "body": {
                        "session_variables": {
                            "x-hasura-role": "public"
                        },
                        "input": {
                            "email": "",
                            "password": ""
                        },
                        "action": {
                            "name": "login"
                        }
                    },
                    "url": "http://host.docker.internal:5000/api/auth/login",
                    "headers": []
                }
            },
            "path": "$",
            "code": "unexpected"
        },
        "message": "http exception when calling webhook"
    }
]
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If someone encounters the same issue this is how I solved it

Add this to **docker-compose.yml** file

```
    extra_hosts:
    - "host.docker.internal:host-gateway"
```

Allow ports **8080** and **5000** in **firewall**

```
 sudo ufw allow 8080 
 sudo ufw allow 5000
```